# end user riddle - cross sign over file or print

Tags: windows-xp

I was speaking to a relative at work, they didn't want me to "access their screen" remotely(and perhaps rightly so)..

They wanted to print something.

They were describing what they were seeing, and I have no idea..

They were in their browser and wanted to print. I said try right click and click print.

He said he did that, and he got a SAVE AS dialog box. I got him out of that.

Then i told him to click File..Print, he did that and said he gets/he described a save as dialog box. I got him out of that again.

I talked him through/ told him to press print screen, open paintbrush, paste.. He got what he wanted to print in there.  He said File or Print has a cross in it. I said , is this separate from the cross in the top right hand corner. He said it's a different thing, it's like a jesus cross.

I have no idea.

Has anybody ever seen anything like that? Anybody know what he was looking at?

Accepted answer requires a screenshot of it!  (not photoshopped!)

Comment: What the whatty what?

Comment: @ignacio <sarcasm>very funny ignacio</sarcasm>

Comment: Your question is not helpful, because you are relying on someone else's view of the screen. Please either go and look for yourself, or get your relative to send you a screen shot.

Comment: @Rudolph I got the information that I could for the time they had. It's over now.  And you're stumped. It's unfortunate that the question wasn't "helpful" for you in trying to solve it!  I think i've just figured it out though. I will post an answer. Be interesting if others have a better one.

Comment: *I just answered it* So obviously it wasn't too vague, incomplete, ambiguous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have read, that when a printer is not installed, then you do or can, get a SAVE AS dialog box.

This link mentions it 
http://thedailyreviewer.com/outlook/view/print-command-only-activates-save-as-option-104653438

I can't test it 'cos on a laptop I use, I have the machine I see,  "Microsoft XPS Document Writer", and I don't want to delete that ('cos i'd want to be be sure i'd get it back without issues.. it's just not worth it to me to risk that - not just yet anyway)..

So, that'd explain the SAVE AS dialog box coming up when choosing PRINT. That was in his browser (probably internet explorer).

He then went MS PAINT, and tried PRINT, and he said about the cross.  And he said he couldn't click PRINT.  Well, I can see what he would've seen. I just bet it was greyed out too. Here is a screenshot from my computer(not his). But the "cross" is the same.

[image]

He most probably saw the + between CTRL and P !!

That's it.

Be interesting if anybody has a better answer.

I just googled about the print and save as, got the printer idea..

And, just opened paint and can see the cross he was talking about! Obviously I never thought of it like that before and clearly neither did anybody else!